# MySQL: First sort for each occurrence, after the remaining

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

How can I ensure non-repetition of the first occurrences of idtag column?

Example: The first 4 (size of values ​​within the IN clause) idtag occurrences can not be 85,85,85,90

DB Schema: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0a683/2

I dont use group by, because sometime i need to limit more than number of ids inside IN clause. Example if i use:

```
SELECT
tr.idreceita,
tr.idtag
FROM tagreceita tr
WHERE tr.idtag IN (85,88,90)
GROUP BY tr.idtag
LIMIT 4
```

It would be ideal if it resulted 4 rows with only values allowed in *tr.idtag IN (85,88,90)*

Thank you!

Comment: `I dont use group by, because sometime i need to limit more than number of ids inside IN clause` also specify the query for this case please

Comment: and you just want three results in record set? `IN (85,88,90)`

Comment: I tried to improve the question.

Comment: This sounds to me you want the unique top 4 off every group based on idtag where the values idtag are 85,88,90 ? .... can you explain in simple plain english what you need??? because i lost any logical sense in the question right now....

Answer (score 1):

The proper way would be to use aggregation:

```
SELECT min(tr.idreceita), tr.idtag
FROM tagreceita tr
WHERE tr.idtag IN (85,88,90)
group by tr.idtag;
```

EDIT:

I see, sometimes you want more things that are in the `in` list.  In that case, probably the easiest approach is to randomize the results:

```
select tr.idreceita, tr.idtag
from tagreceita tr
where tr.idtag IN (85,88,90)
order by rand();
```

This does not guarantee uniqueness, but it is an easy solution.

EDIT II:

The formal solution to get a balanced result uses variables (or `row_number()` in almost any other database):

```
select idreceita, idtag
from (select tr.idreceita, tr.idtag,
             @rn := if(@idtag = tr.idtag, @rn + 1, 1) as rn,
             @idtag := tr.idtag
      from tagreceita tr cross join
           (select @rn := 0, @idtag := -1) const
      where tr.idtag IN (85, 88, 90)
      order by tr.idtag
     ) t
order by rn, idtag
order by rand();
```

Answer (score 0):

> The first 4 (size of values ​​within the IN clause) idtag occurrences can not be 85,85,85,90

erm, you've repeated 85 three times there. Taking a simpler case where you don't want 85,90 to appear in the first 2 entries....

```
SELECT
tr.idreceita,
tr.idtag
FROM tagreceita tr
WHERE tr.idtag IN (85,88,90)
ORDER BY idtag IN (85,90), idtag
```

The `id IN (85,90)` gives a value of 0 or 1 depending on whether it is true or false.

I don't quite understand what you mean by the two values not appearing in the first four rows - perhaps if you could provide a more detailled explanation (including the reasons for trying to acheive this) then I might be able to come up with a more apposite solution.